# What is the "stuck text" that happens on my screen as a byproduct of a plugin? How can I remove it?

Tags: autocompletion, plugin-coc

When I'm using Vim in the terminal, I sometimes get stuff like this:[image]

The square bracket floating is what I'm talking about. When my autocompleter plugin stops completing, sometimes it "forgets" to delete some text and leaves it lying around (like that square bracket up there.) A Ctrl+L refresh fixes it, though.

I'm using coc.nvim right now, but this also happened on YouCompleteMe and clang complete, so I'm not sure what to really think about it.

How can I fix this "stuck text"?

Comment: I suppose this comes down to be using a different terminal emulator and configuring `$TERM` correctly.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! In previously similar questions, as @ChristianBrabandt points out, this is often a terminal configuration issue

Comment: Could you help point me to a previous similar question so I can see what the problem is? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was breaking my head trying to debug this. It turns out it was a problem with my vim colorscheme. I was using Monokai from vim-colorschemes. In the definition for PMenu it specifies all colours as NONE, I think this somehow interferes with the autocomplete engine when it has to resize the popup window. The resize action leaves the debris of random text on the screen.

I worked around this by specifying a background color for the PMenu highlight in the colorscheme.

```
vim ~/.vim/plugged/vim-colorschemes/colors/Monokai.vim
```

changed:

```
hi Pmenu ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=NONE guibg=NONE gui=NONE
```

to

```
hi Pmenu ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=2 cterm=NONE guifg=NONE guibg=#004400 gui=NONE
```

This gives a green background to the popup window, you could modify as you see fit.

Comment: I'm glad this solved the problem for you, but at least for me the problem still showed up even when I used the default colorscheme :/ (In any case, I eventually switched to neovim, which doesn't have this problem.)